# Jquery RemoveClass not working for bootstrap buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, background-color, removeclass

I am having trouble using the Jquery removeClass functionality to disable a certain class. The class definition is given below

```
.btn-purple
{
    background-color: #F1B2E1;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F1B2E1, #E986D0);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F1B2E1, #E986D0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F1B2E1), to(#E986D0));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F1B2E1, #E986D0);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F1B2E1, #E986D0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #F1B2E1, #E986D0);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F1B2E1', endColorstr='#E986D0', GradientType=0);
    border-color: #0055cc #0055cc #003580;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
.btn-purple:hover,
.btn-purple:active,
.btn-purple.active,
.btn-purple.disabled,
.btn-purple[disabled] {
  background-color: #E986D0;
}
```

In the javascript file I have the following

```
$(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(){
        $("#1").removeClass("btn-purple", 1000);
        return false
    });

});
```

And here is the HTML markup for the section I wish to remove the class definition from

```
<div id="1" class="span3 well homeBox opaque btn-purple">
    <span class="siteBoxContent">What do we do?</span>
</div>
```

And here is the error I'm getting while debugging in the Webkit Error Console

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'fx.end[0]')      jquery.effects.core.js:32
```

If I try to remove a class like 'homeBox', the removeClass works fine. Here is the definition for the homeBox class definition

```
.homeBox
{
    position:relative;
    width:26.666666666667%;
    height:200px;
}
```

So I'm guessing jQuery may have a problem with removing classes which have background-image, colour or even the filter attributes. If you require any more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#1").removeClass("btn-purple");
```

Instead of:

```
$("#1").removeClass("btn-purple", 1000);
```

since there is not second argument available for it and `1000` doesn't make any sense there.

Two possible signatures of it are:

```
.removeClass( [className] )
.removeClass( function(index, class) )
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: I am using the jqueryui definition for removeClass. It's defined here at this link [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass)

Answer (score 0):

You use a function signature that doesn't exist:

```
removeClass("classname", integer) // WRONG
```

There's no such possibility in JQuery AFAIK, you can do:

```
.removeClass( [className] )
.removeClass( function(index, class) ) // from version 1.4
```

I don't understand what 1000 stands for, but I bet that removing it should fix the issue.

Comment: The 1000 stands for the duration in which the transition from one class to other should happen. This definition is defined in the jqueryui class definition for removeClass and can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/)